# RSpec NoMethodError: "undefined method `describe' for main Object"

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to learn Rspec. My ruby project in eclipse is as follows -

[image]

The code-

```
require 'rspec'
require './RubyOffRailsTuts/classes/furlong'

describe Furlong do
end
```

The error-

```
/RubyOffRailsTuts/specs/furlong_spec.rb:6:in `<main>': undefined 
method `describe' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Did not get any useful answers online. How do I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### The solution

Call `RSpec.describe` instead of just `describe`.

```
require 'rspec'
require './RubyOffRailsTuts/classes/furlong'

RSpec.describe Furlong do
end
```

#### The reason it works

You can tell from the error message "*undefined method `describe' for main Object*" that the underlying problem is that you are trying to call `describe` on the the basic Object `main`, which does not have a `describe` method.

Comment: The problem went away when I removed 'require rspec', did `gem install rspec` after cd-ing into the ruby 2 bin folder, adding these rspec libraries to my build path and running the spec as a test and not script. I have deleted the above project a while ago, but I will try to recreate. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Method 2 does not work if you have config.disable_monkey_patching! in rspec_helper.  See @sevenseacat answer below.

Answer (score 48):

Alternative to prefacing `describe` as `RSpec.describe`, you can add

```
config.expose_dsl_globally = true
```

to your `spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: Only works when put after `config.disable_monkey_patching!`
If that line is uncommented

Answer (score 23):

You prefix `describe` with `RSpec`, eg. `RSpec.describe` because it sounds like you're using a modern version of RSpec that disables monkey patching.

Answer (score 20):

I agree with sevenseacat that you're likely using a modern version of RSpec that disables monkey patching.

This disabling is done by default when the `spec_helper.rb` file is created when you do something like

```
$ rails generate rspec:install
```

In `spec_helper.rb`, you'll see a section that looks like this:

```
# Limits the available syntax to the non-monkey patched syntax that is
# recommended. For more details, see:
#   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax
#   - http://www.teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
#   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3#new__config_option_to_disable_rspeccore_monkey_patching
config.disable_monkey_patching!
```

You can comment out that last line.

However, the recommended approach is not to use monkey patching, and use `RSpec.describe`.

Answer (score 2):

If someone by any chance gets a similar brain blackout for couple minutes like myself a while ago and does use:

```
ruby spec/yourspec.rb
```

instead of

```
rspec spec/yourspec.rb
```

And is completely stunned why this did work a minute ago and does not right now when nothing has changed - this is exactly the error that pops in.

Comment: That someone was me!! THANK YOU!